# Free calendar server?

Tags: ldap, email, calendar

I am looking for free calendar server who can authenticate to LDAP server. I want our users to use thunderbird lightning with calendar server. We have mail server with devcot and squirlmail for webmail. Could you recommend me calendar server?

Answer (score 4):

The [DAViCal](http://www.davical.org/) CalDAV server will probably do what you're looking for (and has [LDAP authentication](http://wiki.davical.org/w/Configuration/LDAP)). I use it with Mozilla Sunbird and it works great.

Comment: Is it easy for installation and configuration? I am more windows than linux user.

Answer (score 1):

Zimbra has it all

Comment: I know about Zimbra but if we go with zimbra we have to move all e-mail accounts with zimbra. We have more than 800 users and we just cannot afford this migration. I am interested in DAViCal is it easy for installation adn configuration? I am not advanced linux user I am more a windows guy. Kronolith Calendar Application - can it be install separately from the whole Horde framework?

Comment: Yeah, zimbra might be a bit of an overkill here. I don't know about DaviCal, you'd better ask Evan Anderson

Answer (score 1):

We use the Horde framework, which also has programs for calendaring, tasks, e-mail, and a bunch of others. Horde.org is the place to go.

Answer (score 1):

zarafa (http://www.zarafa.com) is a great exchange replacement. You can even synchronize smartphones with it using z-push.